# What is the shortest, best, cleanest way to set a private field via Reflection in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection

Hi I've already worked with Reflection in Java. But if you are using the java standards (e.g. injecting a private field) you have to write a lot of code to get the job done.

What is the shortest way to inject a private field in a Java Object? Are there implementations in widely used and production ready libraries?

Comment: Be aware that this may not work in modular Java applications.  You cannot alter private fields by any means, if the containing package is not opened by its module.

Comment: @VGR can you post a link about that matter?

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The "One-Liner"**

```
FieldUtils.writeField(Object target, String fieldName, Object value, boolean forceAccess)
```

If your Project uses **Apache Commons Lang**
 the shortest way to set a value via reflection is to use the static Method **'writeField'** in the class **'org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils'**

The following simple example shows a Bookstore-Object with a field paymentService. The code shows how the private field is set two times with a different value.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;

public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Bookstore bookstore = new Bookstore();

        //Just one line to inject the field via reflection
        FieldUtils.writeField(bookstore, "paymentService",new Paypal(), true);
        bookstore.pay(); // Prints: Paying with: Paypal

        //Just one line to inject the field via reflection
        FieldUtils.writeField(bookstore, "paymentService",new Visa(), true);
        bookstore.pay();// Prints Paying with: Visa
    }

    public static class Paypal implements  PaymentService{}

    public static class Visa implements  PaymentService{}

    public static class Bookstore {
        private  PaymentService paymentService;
        public void pay(){
            System.out.println("Paying with: "+ this.paymentService.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }
}
```

You can get the lib via maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It's not one liner if there is hidden code behind the lib, That's like making a big function and calling it from one method and calling it a one liner.

Comment: @SamzSakerz I understand what you're saying but that argument can be used for  99% of what are considered "one-liners".

Answer (score 18):

Without using external libraries you need to:

- get the `Field` instance
- set the field instance as accessible
- set the new value

As follow:

```
Field f1 = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("field");
f1.setAccessible(true);
f1.set(obj, "new Value");
```

Comment: I favor this approach since it doesn't depend on any external library. But, anyway it depends on each user-scenario.

Comment: You should set the accessibility back to 'false' after setting the value.

Comment: @AndreasHauschild It is not required to set again accessible to false if you don't reuse the Field f1. You are not really modifying the visibility of field on the original class, but only explicitly saying that you like to access the private content of field f1.

Comment: True but you change it for the given object. If it is used by other code which you can't control it could be a problem.

Comment: @AndreasHauschild No, if you create a new Field variable with Field fNew = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("field"); you can't change it without explicitly setting accessible to true. It means that the changes are only local to the instance of Field f1.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Thx for this hint. You are right. Again learned something ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the `Spring Framework`, there is an utils class named `ReflectionUtils`

Here is a way to inject a value into a private field.

According to :

`findField(Class<?> clazz, String name, Class<?> type)`

and

`setField(Field field, @Nullable Object target, @Nullable Object value)`

You can write:

```
final Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(Foo.class, "name", String.class)
ReflectionUtils.setField(field, targetObject, "theNewValue")
```

It is certainly not the shortest way to write this but it is shorter than the basic JDK tools to do this and I trusts people who are developing Spring so I am confident enough. Just be sure you actually really need reflection before doing this.

Plus if this is for a testing purpose, there is `ReflectionTestUtils` that provides you some methods too.

You'll find everything in the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: In contrast to ReflectionTestUtils, springs ReflectionUtils is internal use only. You can use it but it may break in future versions without warning

Answer (score 0):

what I would do is make this a helper method.

```
public static void changeField(Class cc, String field, String newValue) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field f = cc.getDeclaredField(field);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(cc, newValue);
    f.setAccessible(false);
}
```

and call it like the following

```
changeField(cc, "field", "newValue");
```