# How can I move a report element dynamically?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to add an element to the page which I can position dynamically at runtime. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way and you probably shouldn't try what I explain below. Most of the time, it's a sign that your report design has a mistake somewhere and you should consider other options, first.

Unlike many properties (where you can use a `<propertyExpression>` element to refer to a field or parameter, here is a list: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html), this isn't possible for the coordinate and size of a `JRBaseElement`.

But there is a hack: You need to run the report yourself, for example from Java.

Eventually, you will call `JasperFillManager.fillReport()`. There are two versions. One just takes an `InputStream` but the other takes a `JasperReport` instance. You can get one using

```
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(stream);
```

That will give you access to all bands (type `JRBand`).

Next, you need to find your element. Get the UUID from the `.jrxml` file. Search the respective band for a child with this UUID (`JRBand.getChildren()`).

Now you can call `setX()` and `setHeight()` on the element to change the X coordinate or width.

Y and height are a different matter. Those are private fields. If you really have to change those as well, look here: [What is the shortest, best, cleanest way to set a private field via Reflection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744482/what-is-the-shortest-best-cleanest-way-to-set-a-private-field-via-reflection-i)

Note that you should be careful not to move the element outside of the bounding box of the band.

Comment: In general I think you should never need to do this, it's normally an error in design, because you are not actually interested in the position of a field but instead the position of what is in that field. Using print when expression and stretch types most cases can be solved. If everything is dynamic you probably should use dynamic jasper or a similar library

Comment: Agreed. I have to do this because of a bug in a tool that does digital signatures.